# Group the X axis by two variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I need to group the X axis of a bar graph by 2 variables. When trying to perform this operation, it concatenates the 2 variables which causes one of them to be repeated, which is not required.

I send below the code to consider:

**Data code**

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Lista de países de Europa
paises_europa = ['España', 'Francia', 'Alemania', 'Italia', 'Reino Unido', 'Portugal', 'Países Bajos']

# Lista de ciudades correspondientes a cada país
ciudades = [['Madrid', 'Barcelona'],
            ['París'],
            ['Berlín', 'Múnich', 'Hamburgo'],
            ['Roma', 'Milán'],
            ['Londres', 'Birmingham', 'Manchester'],
            ['Lisboa', 'Oporto'],
            ['Ámsterdam', 'Róterdam']]

# Crear una lista que asocie cada país con sus ciudades correspondientes
data = []
for pais, lista_ciudades in zip(paises_europa, ciudades):
    for ciudad in lista_ciudades:
        data.append((pais, ciudad, random.randint(5, 50)))

# Crear el DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Pais', 'Ciudad', 'Tiendas'])

df
```

**Graph code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Calcular el valor máximo en las barras
max_valor = df['Tiendas'].max()

# Calcular el rango para el eje Y
y_min = 0
y_max = max_valor + 5

# Crear la figura y los ejes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

# Definir colores
bar_color = '#4a8a52'

# Graficar un gráfico de barras
ax.bar(df.index, df['Tiendas'], color=bar_color)

# Etiquetas en el eje X
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels([f'{pais} - {ciudad}' for pais, ciudad in zip(df['Pais'], df['Ciudad'])], rotation=90)

# Establecer el rango del eje Y
ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)

# Etiqueta en el eje Y como números enteros
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(integer=True))

# Título
plt.title('Count of Stores by Country and City')

# Título del eje X
ax.set_xlabel('Country / City')

# Título del eje Y
ax.set_ylabel('Stores')

# Etiquetas en las barras
for i, val in enumerate(df['Tiendas']):
    ax.text(i, val + 1, str(val), ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=10)

# Ajustar el diseño
plt.tight_layout()

# Mostrar el gráfico
plt.show()
```

The result of this code is:

[image]

While the graph I need is:

[image]

Comment: to get the bars size by side, you will need this:  `ax = df.set_index(['Pais', 'Ciudad'])['Tiendas'].unstack().plot.bar()`...  you might need to tweak other params.